# Building a Joomla component from an existing PHP script

Tags: php, database-design, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am working on a freelancer site that will use Joomla as the base.  I would like to create a custom component for the freelancer functionality and was wondering if there is a way to convert an existing freelancer PHP program (specifically Ilance) into a Joomla component. I have a license for Ilance and thought about using the wrapper in Joomla for it.  But this option will not work for me.  Instead, I would like to add all the functionality of Ilance into Joomla without creating it from scratch.

Comment: No it is not possible convert it to a component. Not sure how you script is written, but Joomla components are MVC based.

Comment: You'll have to either rewrite Ilance the Joomla way, or as you said, write a wrapper and leave the Ilance code untouched. Neither will be easy, but the lesser of two evils is the wrapper option (think updates). Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

OFC you can do that. Joomla components should be MVC but they don't need to. They can actually be any (crappy) code you want. That's why everyone calls himself a pro joomla developer ;)
You only need to work your way into creating the basic joomla bootstrapper file and some installation xml and off you go.